# Unable to connect after reboot in Google Compute Engine

Tags: svn, ssh, google-compute-engine

Due to excessive use I had to upgrade my machine which led to a reboot.
After that I'm unable to connect through PuTTY, only using Google console.

Also, my SVN repository is there, and I can't connect to it either.

I looked at the firewall rules in 'VPC Network', and they are the same before the reboot :

[image]

The output of iptables -L :

```
[newuser@google-server ~]$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_trusted  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_trusted  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_trusted  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_trusted  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_trusted (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_trusted_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_trusted_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_trusted_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_trusted_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_trusted_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_trusted_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_trusted (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_trusted_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_trusted_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_trusted_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_trusted_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_trusted_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_trusted_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_trusted  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_trusted  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_trusted (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_trusted_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_trusted_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_trusted_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_trusted_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_trusted_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_trusted_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

My ssh key is still in `.ssh/authorized_keys` but when using PuTTY, even before asking for the user, it dies with:

```
Network error: connection timeout
```

When trying to update my SVN local copy it dies "because host didn't respond".

What I've already looked:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046736/unable-to-connect-to-google-compute-engine-using-in-browser-ssh?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535306/cant-ssh-connect-to-google-cloud-compute-engine-after-rebooting?rq=1) don't adress the problem since my access using Google console works perfectly
- Neither [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389832/google-compute-engine-unable-to-connect-to-vm?rq=1), because it relates to issues regarding first time connecting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that **the IP changed after reboot**.

I think it would be a good call to inform that besides reboot the machine may suffer from an IP change, unless you [reserve a static external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address).

Fortunately, this wasn't my production server, so the change just caused a few hours of frustration for me till I discovered the problem.