# Compute engine became inaccessible after a reboot

Tags: google-compute-engine

After having used the VM for several days, I decided to restart the VM so that I can do some performance bench marking with minimal processes running.
The VM did come up but I am no longer able to access it through Putty or browser based SSH. The private/public keys are all in place and they are the same ones that were used to get access before.

I get the following error when using the Google provided browser based SSH window..

Connection Failed
      We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible 
     causes of this issue.

My colleagues who used to have access to the same machines are also not able to access it anymore. So my client machine isn't the problem. 
The VM instances dashboard says the instance is running.

Any thoughts on what could have gone wrong and how to debug this?  The log files that I can access from the VM instances dashboard don't indicate any errors.

Thanks

Comment: I tried the netcat command to test the port accessibility as follows:                   
   nc -zv -w 10 x.x.x.x 80 20 22 where x.x.x.x is my external IP address..I got a bunch of connection timeout messages back.  Something is wrong at the network level it looks like.

Comment: How did you reboot the VM? From inside the VM or from the web console? Have you looked at the serial console for any clues? Could you have broken one of the scripts used during boot? If all else fails you can attach the virtual disk of your failing instance as secondary disk on a working instance to look at the logfiles on disk.

Comment: Started the VM from the web console. I may have found the problem...Recently I increased the boot disk size and attached a new file system (sda2) to use the increased space..The serial console shows the following error:                                                                       
        3610.091958] EXT4-fs (sda2): Unrecognized mount option "deafults" or missing value
You are in emerg
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

How do I recover from this?

Comment: If I can get access to /etc/fstab file, I can fix this error.

Comment: I don't have time to write a detailed answer today. The summary is you can create a new temporary VM and attach the misconfigured disk as a secondary disk such that you can mount it and fix it. It may also be possible to fix the problem through the serial console, but I don't remember for sure if you can do that.

Comment: Thanks kasperd. Took your advice and moved the disk to a new instance. It is all good now.  Thanks

Comment: For future reference if you need to access the machine but cannot SSH, you can access via the serial console by following the advice in my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123487/cannot-ssh-to-google-vm-engine/47137036#47137036

Comment: I could bet that you were a victim of the IP change after reboot: https://serverfault.com/questions/881108/unable-to-connect-after-reboot-in-google-compute-engine/881109#881109

Answer (score 1):

In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) you can find ssh troubleshooting tips for common Compute Engine ssh errors. As your problem  was due to a /etc/fstab misconfiguration, a valid solution is [attaching your disk to a new instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#move_boot_disk).